# Powershell null-valued expression error

Tags: javascript, powershell, internet-explorer, powershell-3.0, ie-automation

I'm new to Powershell, and I've been struggling with this issue for longer than I care to admit. I am trying to automate the filling out of an intranet webform, and I thought this would be very simple. I've already got the login component worked out, but I am having trouble with completing the "Last Name" text box on the form.

```
$url = "www.myintranetsite.com"
$lastname="Smith" 
$firstname="John" 
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; 
} 
$ie.Document.getElementById("ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_LAST_NAME_LBL").value = 
$lastname
```

The error flagging is that I cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. The offender is the "ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_LAST_NAME_LBL"

Any suggestions as to why $lastname would be returning as a null value?

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf8Ht.jpg
![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE71n.jpg

Comment: did you mean to miss the ending " on the URL?

Comment: Oops, fixed it. Thanks for catching!

Answer (score 0):

It is not the last name that is the problem. It is the element. Can you do something like this?

```
$doc = $ie.document
$lastname = $doc.getElementById('ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_LAST_NAME_LBL')
$lastname.Value = "smith"
```

And use the single quote on element id instead of double

Once you get the $lastname object defined, check its member using `| get-member` to see if `value` is an available property

Comment: Hmmm, value doesn't seem to be an available property.

Comment: Can I ask if you are using windows 10? because I had a similar code that worked on win7 but fails on win10 on that line. Perhaps it is the version of IE. I have not really tried to debug it.

Comment: Nope, I'm using Windows 7. 32 bit system. IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your trying to add a value to Label.

Labels dont hold a value.

https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tag_label.asp

It looks like based on your picture that the label is for **ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_LAST_NAME**

```
$url = "www.myintranetsite.com"
$lastname="Smith" 
$firstname="John" 
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; 
} 
$ie.Document.getElementById('ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_BO_NAME$542$').value = $lastname
```

Comment: Thanks ArcSet, so how would I fill in the Last Name box with "Smith"? What would that syntax look like?

Comment: posted what should be working code, If that doesnt work then post the source of the page so i can find the name of the input

Comment: I appreciate your help, but the Source code is 2000+ lines. Does this help at all?

</DIV></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height='15' colspan='4'></td>
<td colspan='2' rowspan='3'  valign='top' align='left'>
<DIV id='win2divlblERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_LAST_NAME'><label for='ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_LAST_NAME' class='PSEDITBOXLABEL' id='ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_LAST_NAME_LBL'>Last Name</label>
</DIV></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height='1' colspan='4'></td>
<td></td>

Comment: I did, and I got the same message.

Comment: You need to find the Input tag...you keep posting the label tag

Comment: <td rowspan='2' nowrap='nowrap'  valign='top' align='left'>
<DIV id='win2divERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_BO_NAME$542$'><input type='text' name='ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_BO_NAME$542$' id='ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_BO_NAME$542$' tabindex='902' value=""  class='PSEDITBOX' style='width:137px; ' maxlength='130'  />
</DIV></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height='16'></td>
<td colspan='5' rowspan='2'  valign='top' align='left'>
<DIV id='win2divlblERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_BO_NAME$542$'><label for='ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_BO_NAME$542$' class='PSEDITBOXLABEL' id='ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_BO_NAME$542$_LBL'>Organization Name</label>

Comment: so find the ID for the input and place the ID name into getElementById

Comment: I tried as many different things as I could, and nothing is working. I'm wondering if my company has this blocked for some reason? Or if I lack admin access? I'm not sure what else it could be.

Comment: copy and paste exactly what i have, You will notice that the double qoutes " are now single qoutes'

Comment: Ok, I tried it, didn't work. The odd thing is that I can get it to work with several other sites, just not this one.

Comment: Yes. Null valued expression on: 
$ie.Document.getElementById('ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_BO_NAME$542$').value = $lastname

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:18 char:1
+ $ie.Document.getElementById('ERM_SEARCH_WRK_ERM_BO_NAME$542$').value = $lastname
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 0):

I face the same error when trying to click on a button:

```
    $ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $ie.navigate("MyURL")
    $ie.visible = $true
    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000;  }
    $doc = $ie.document
$btn=$doc.getElementByID('ctl00_PageHeader1_ctl06_c_b_Start_c_b_View_c_b_ExportDefaultButton_ExportDefaultButton')
    $btn.click()
```

the error is: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

Windows 10 x64

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30738950)